# Finding the maximum area of a rectangle

Tags: area

I'm having trouble with this problem and I need help to solve it...

A person has $800$ ft of fencing. He wishes to form a rectangular enclosure and then divide it into three sections by running two lengths of fence parallel to one side. What should the dimensions of the enclosure be in order to maximize the enclosed area?

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: This is a word problem. Have you managed to write it in a mathematical (algebraic) language, to start with?

Comment: You can write some relations between perimeter, that is 800, and area of the rectangle

Comment: TOTAL FENCING =2L+2B+2L=4L+2B=800                                                                                                                                      
         AREA = LB = L(400-2L)                                                                                                    
                     =2(200L-L^2)                                                                                                         
                      =2{100^2-(L-100)^2}
maximum area is    2*100^2=20000 ft^2

Comment: Looks like you've almost solved it then ... Just for which $L$ will $100^2-(L-100)^2$ be maximal? (And then what is $B$?)